# Python PyMuPDF looping next pages

Tags: python, pymupdf

I'm using below code to open a PDF file and convert into an image file as output. Now, i'm trying to figure it out how can I loop the next page and convert it as same output file. Any help is much appreciated!

```
# display image on the canvas
def openFile(self, _value=False):
    global fileImg, output


    path = os.path.dirname(ustr(self.filePath)) if self.filePath else '.'
    fileImg = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, '%s - Choose file' % __appname__, path)

    # convert PDF to image file
    pdffile = fileImg
    doc = fitz.open(pdffile)
    page = doc.loadPage(0)
    pix = page.getPixmap(matrix=fitz.Matrix(100 / 72, 100 / 72))
    output = "output.png"
    pix.writePNG(output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply loop over the `doc` object to get the next pages.

```
doc = fitz.open(file_name)  # open document
for page in doc:  # iterate through the pages
    pix = page.getPixmap(...)  # render page to an image
    pix.writePNG("page-%i.png" % page.number)  # store image as a PNG
```

check the [**PyMuPDF documentation**](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-make-images-from-document-pages) for more information.

Comment: what parameter do we pass in this part `pix = page.getPixmap(...) `?

Comment: @YasserKhalil try taking a look at the original documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use minecart and use this snippet to split pdf into images

```
import minecart
from PIL import Image    
file =open('Yourdoc.pdf','rb')
    doc = minecart.Document(file)
    page=doc.iter_pages()
    pageref=[]
    for j,i in enumerate( page):
        im = i.images[0].as_pil()
        im.save(f"folderlocation/{j}.jpg")
```